# Rails 4 coffeescript and erb on ajax answer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my app, I do an ajax request and the server respond me a javascript, which is executed properly. The javascript is on the file `app/views/users/set_role.js.erb`. However, when I try to change it to `app/views/users/set_role.js.coffee.erb` I have the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/set_role, application/set_role with {
  :locale=>[:en], 
  :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], 
  :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]
}. Searched in:
```

Is it possible to have a coffeescript file with erb code on Rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

You have not define the coffee format so Rails did not looked for it, and then complains about that extension.
Did you install the coffee gem?

https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails

And then just use

app/views/users/set_role.js.coffee

Comment: I have `coffee` gem installed, you can see it is cited on the handlers. `.js.coffee` works, However `.js.coffee.erb` don't.

Comment: Don't, I'll stick with `.erb` up to monday, when I get back to work :-) I let you know if I found